# submitting an asp.net MVC 3 form using jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am working on ASP.NET MVC 3 application and I have a jquery dialogue with Ok button. On click of OK I want to submit a form using jquery AJAX.

My ajax call looks like this:

```
$("#free-trial").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   autoResize: true,
   buttons: {
       "OK": function () {
           if (notvalid()) {
               $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
               $("#dialog-freetrial-insufficientdata").dialog({ dialogClass: 'transparent' });
               $("#dialog-freetrial-insufficientdata").dialog("open");
           }
           else {
               $('#frmCreateTrialAccount').live('submit', function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   $.ajax({
                       cache: false,
                       async: true,
                       type: "POST",
                       url: $(this).attr('action'),
                       data: $(this).serialize(),
                       success: function (data) {
                           alert(data);
                       }
                   });
               });
               jQuery(this).dialog('close');
           }
       }
   },
   open: function () {
       $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("OK")').focus();
       $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("OK")').addClass('customokbutton');
   }
```

});

where as form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateTrialAccount", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
              new { Id = "frmCreateTrialAccount" } ))
{

}
```

and controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateTrialAccount(FormCollection form) {
    return Json("dummy data");
}
```

but form is not submitted on this method.

I have these files included in layout page:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please suggest me solution to this.

Comment: Look like everything is fine. Have you checked that the submit event is hit? Do an alert or console.log in `$('#frmCreateTrialAccount').live('submit',`.

Comment: yes, i try and it doesnt show alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh sorry for that comment I made, your issue is that you are binding the form's submit action where you should have been submitting it already. If you want to bind the form's submit then declare it outside `$("#free-trial").dialog({`. Then you can have the ajax post method in a separate function so you can call it in both the binding code and in the `$("#free-trial").dialog({`.

```
var form = $('#frmCreateTrialAccount');
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

So just to make it clear remove the following lines of code:

```
$('#frmCreateTrialAccount').live('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
// and the ending 
});
```

Comment: Hi von: Thanks for the response. If I remove that then a popup opens on click of Ok button with all the html of the page. Just to make things clear, Ok button is not inside the form. It is jquery ui dialog Ok button and form is located on jquery ui dialog

Comment: Yes I understand where the `OK` button is. What I don't understand is why would "all the html page" would show up. The ajax post will happen if `if (notvalid())` is NOT true. And when the post happens you are just alerting the result, at least for now. Unless you are writing out the result of the post, which you have not shown in your code. Have you tried it btw?

Comment: Hi Von: I am not writing out anything. Controller action is just returning json which i posted in question and success method alerts it

Comment: Okay so what is the problem with my suggestion? And have you tried it already and what's the issue with it if you had?

Comment: In ajax call I am using  url: $(this).attr('action'),
                                data: $(this).serialize(),  what does $(this) means, I think it should be form id ?

Comment: I removed the part which you suggested and it is showing whole page html on popup. before that it was giving error when i had those lines. that live is not available for [object object]

Comment: Oh my bad, yes you have to reference the form and use it in your ajax. See my updated answer and see if it helps - it should now.